# Tratamento ao converter dado

Tags: android

Galera quero converter String em Double já sei como fazer, mas minha string tem ,(virgula) e o double não aceita, como faço pra transformar essa virgula em ponto?
alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace pega o primeiro item e substitui pelo segundo na variável aplicada.

```
string = string.replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: mano, tem como explicar melhor pq deu erro aqui, coloquei String = txt.replace(",","."); txt é a minha string ela possui o valor que quero tratar

Comment: consegui agora deu.

Comment: como eu faria nesse caso:   txtSaldo.setText(); = txtSaldo.getText().toString().replace(",", ".");     ta dando erro quero fazer esse tratamento em uma TextView.